# Input field rises above rest of inputs if <h4> tag is added below it

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a modal and I'm trying to add an error message under the input field if a user enters an invalid value. However, as soon as I enter the value, the input rises above the rest of the fields. This is when I tried to type a zero after 'f'

```
            <div>
              <div //the div that contains all 4 input fields
                className="side-by-side"
                style={{
                  display: "flex",
                  flexDirection: "row",
                  justifyContent: "space-between",
                }}
              >
                  <div>
                <ModalInput
                  type="text"
                  id="name"
                  value={company.name}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    this.editCompanyArr(index, "name", e)
                  }
                 
                ></ModalInput>
                {!validInput && <h4>Please enter a valid name</h4>} //this the heading causing problem
                </div>
                <ModalInput
                  type="text"
                  id="website"
                  value={company.website}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    this.editCompanyArr(index, "website", e)
                  }
                ></ModalInput> //have omitted rest of inputs 
                <AddIconButtonMinus
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() => this.deleteCompany(index)}
                >
                </AddIconButtonMinus>
              </div>
              { index != newCompanies.length - 1 && <hr></hr> }             
            </div>
```

I would like the heading to just be added under the input and make the input aligned with the rest of the inputs

This is the styles.js for the input fields:

```
export const ModalInput = styled.input`
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #f5f6f9;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #f5f6f9;
  height: 100%;
  width: ${props => props.width || 'auto'};
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make your `<h4>` tag which shows error `position: absolute` and then set its top bottom etc. css properties accordingly.

I can help you if you have any working fiddle.